# Computer Vision и графика

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv

Пригодится ли разработчику Computer Vision опыт работы с графикой (OpenGl, DirectX ... )?
Как по мне обе области в той или иной степени работаю с изображениями. Но на hh например для CV не требуют вышеперечисленных библиотек.
Графика в основном используется в gamedev - будет ли от этих навыков прок в зрении?

Comment: Если делать CV для realtime, его придется считать на GPU.

Comment: @gbg можете для новичков пояснить поподробнее :)

Comment: Проку будет не так много, т.к. тот опыт - для создания и вывода графики, а opencv - для обработки.  Приобретенная эрудиция в форматах графических данных будет полезна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, пригодится. Я работаю в области компьютерного зрения и использую OpenGL для генерации тестовых данных.